# extending exception from SoapFault. WSDL

Tags: php, exception, soap, wsdl, soapfault

it possible ?

e.g.:

Server:

```
class Service
{
    public function methodCall()
    {
        ...
        throw new ExceptionEtc(...);
        ...
    }
}
```

custom exception:

```
class ExceptionEtc extends SoapFault
{
    // ...
}
```

Client:

```
try{
   ...
    $client->methodCall();
}
catch(ExceptionEtc $e){
    // !
}
```

all exceptions are of **SoapFault type** (object(SoapFault)). Needed custom type (ExceptionEtc., etc.). 
How to do that ? What add to WSDL scheme ? if it is possible for php, please give an simple example with wsdl scheme.

Comment: I suppose you are targeting this to an specific Java SOAP/WSDL implementation? Which will make the question slightly different and findable using the SO search.

Comment: No, this question relates only to php